# Can't open Firefox with profile (not temporary) with Selenium

Tags: firefox, selenium

I want start firefox with my custom profile, and when I add some plugins (for example) in this session starting from selenium I want he do not forgot them.

I started selenium server

```
start "JAVA Selenium Server" java -jar selenium-server.jar -interactive -firefoxProfileTemplate "D:\Ogame\SeleniumStaticProfile"
```

Then in selenium server

```
cmd=getNewBrowserSession&1=*custom firefox.exe -p SeleniumStatic -no-remote&2=http://www.google.com
cmd=open&1=httttp://www.hotmail.com
cmd=open&1=httttp://www.google.pl
```

and i'm gettings error something like:

```
www.goole.com havent rights to read properties Window.seleniumMarker1299...
```

All log:

> cmd=getNewBrowserSession&1=*custom firefox.exe -p SeleniumStatic
>   -no-remote&2=ht tttp://www.google.com 13:54:50.817 INFO - ---> Requesting
>   htttttp://localhost:4444/selenium-server/driver
>   ?cmd=getNewBrowserSession&1=*custom
>   firefox.exe -p SeleniumStatic
>   -no-remote&2=h tttttp://www.google.com 13:54:50.823 INFO - Command request:
>   getNewBrowserSession[*custom
>   firefox.exe -p  SeleniumStatic
>   -no-remote, htttttp://www.google.com] on session null 13:54:50.824 INFO -
>   creating new remote session
>   13:54:50.832 INFO - Allocated session
>   ad3e48137d024959863ab8bb4c297d55 for
>   httttp: //www.google.com, launching...
>   13:54:54.615 INFO - Got result:
>   OK,ad3e48137d024959863ab8bb4c297d55 on
>   session a
>   d3e48137d024959863ab8bb4c297d55
>   cmd=open&1=http://www.wp.pl
>   13:55:23.588 INFO - ---> Requesting
>   httttp://localhost:4444/selenium-server/driver
>   ?cmd=open&1=htttttp://www.wp.pl&sessionId=ad3e48137d024959863ab8bb4c297d55
>   13:55:23.595 INFO - Command request:
>   open[htttttp://www.wp.pl, ] on session
>   ad3e481 37d024959863ab8bb4c297d55
>   13:55:23.596 WARN - you appear to be
>   changing domains from
>   httttp://www.google.com  to
>   htttttp://www.wp.pl this may lead to a
>   'Permission denied' from the browser
>   (unless it is running as  *iehta or
>   *chrome, or alternatively the selenium server is runnttting in proxy
>   injection mode) 13:55:23.691 INFO -
>   Got result: Witrynie
>   http://www.google.com nie udzielono
>   u prawnien do odczytania wlasciwosci
>   Window.document z
>    on sessi on
>   ad3e48137d024959863ab8bb4c297d55

Of course I have entered proxy in Firefox SeleniumStatic profile (localhost:4444)

What am I doing wrong?
Sorry for my bad english :/

Answer (score 0):

Change your commands to look like the following

```
cmd=getNewBrowserSession&1=*firefox -no-remote&2=http://www.google.com
cmd=open&1=httttp://www.hotmail.com
cmd=open&1=httttp://www.google.pl
```

YOu don't need to specify the profile since you have already done that when starting the Selenium Server.

Comment: @Automatedester 
`INFO - ---> Requesting http://localhost:4444/selenium-server/driver
?cmd=getNewBrowserSession&1=*firefox -no-remote&2=http://www.google.com
08:44:15.263 INFO - Checking Resource aliases
08:44:15.265 INFO - Command request: getNewBrowserSession[*firefox -no-remote, h
ttp://www.google.com] on session null
08:44:15.269 INFO - creating new remote session
08:44:15.285 INFO - Got result: Failed to start new browser session: org.openqa.
selenium.server.browserlaunchers.InvalidBrowserExecutableException: The specifie
d path to the browser executable is invalid. on session null`

Comment: remove the -no-remote, I am sure its because there is a space

Comment: maybe.. but I wan't to run it with custom because when you start firefox in this way.. you can add plugins, favorite www.. and when you run it again you have it.. wothout custom you don't.. profile cache is reverted..